# remove element from vector and adding that element to a new vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `std::vector<int> numList` and it contains `{9,6,3,3,2,1}`. What I want, is during the loop, once we hit `9 % 3 == 0`, I want to put `9` into a new vector `v1` and `3` into `v2`, while erasing these numbers from the original list. And repeat the process every time the mod results in `0`.

I have this but it crashes:

```
for(i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < listSize; j++)
    {
        if(i != j)
        {
            remainder = numList[i] % numList[j];

            if(numList[i] % numList[j] == 0)
            {
                //cout<< numList[i] << " " << numList[j]<<endl;
                v1.push_back(numList[i]);
                v2.push_back(numList[j]);

                numList.erase(numList.begin() + i);
                numList.erase(numList.begin() + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're aware that `numList.size()` changes, and thus `i` and `j` might not be less than `numList.size()` anymore?

Comment: so as long as i compensate for the size of numList, this is still proper syntax?

Comment: Return a std::tuple of three vectors and do not alter the input vector

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to discard `listSize` and use `numList.size()`, that will give you the current size. You might as well delete the whole `remainder = numList[i] % numList[j];`, while we're at it. I guess you're not using `remainder` afterwards, remove it completely.

**Important:**

1. The element of larger index should be removed first, then the smaller.
2. You shouldn't increment `i` and `j` in the cycle where erasing occurred - you don't want to skip any elements.
3. There's `1` in among the elements that will pair up with anything. Fix the condition.

To conclude, this is **not cool**:

```
int i; // just absurd
// list of variable declarations that are not needed right now, or not needed at all

for(i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
```

This is much better:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numList.size(); i++)
```

Comment: ok slight confusion. What do you mean don't let them increment? Should i not have the erase inside of the loop? but that doesn't seem right in my head

Comment: No, it needs to be in the loop, but `erase` makes `i` and `j` already be index of the next element, if you increment it afterwards, you'll skip that elements.

Comment: so are you saying i need to increment i and j BEFORE using erase? if so, how can you do that with erase being in the loop? i and j won't increment until a cycle is done right?

Comment: `if(condition) { erase } else { increment }` and don't do `++i` and `++j` in the `for` "increment" section.

Comment: ok i see...funny thing is i've never done a for loop without i++ part so i was confused haha

Comment: And remember to do (1), then see how it goes. Maybe you'll also want the larger elements to end up in `v1` and smaller in `v2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 9, 6, 3, 3, 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); )
    {
        std::vector<int>::size_type j = i + 1;
        while ( j < v.size() && v[i] % v[j] ) j++;
        if ( j != v.size() )
        {
            v1.push_back( v[i] );
            v2.push_back( v[j] );
            v.erase( std::next( v.begin(), j ) );    
            v.erase( std::next( v.begin(), i ) );    
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    for ( int x : v1 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : v2 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
9 6 2 
3 3 1
```

Take into account that the index in the inner loop can not be less than the index in the outer loop for matching elements.